# How to use sed to postfix specified letter in specified line

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file like this:

```
www,/something else/,ese
www,/something else/,aes
arc,/something else/,ese
old,/something else/,ese
```

I wanna postfix ",0" to all lines except "www,/something else/,aes" with ",1","old,/something else/,ese" with nothing.
So the result should be like that:

```
www,/something else/,ese,0
www,/something else/,aee,1
arc,/something else/,ese,0
old,/something else/,ese
```

How can I made that? Thanks.

Comment: i think the 2nd line in the output would be `www,/something else/,aes,1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work.

```
awk 'p="0" $0~/aes/ {p=1} $0~/old/ {p=""} {print $0(p~/0|1/?",":"")p}' file
www,/something else/,ese,0
www,/something else/,aes,1
arc,/something else/,ese,0
old,/something else/,ese
```

Comment: another similar way `awk '{p=","0}/aes/{p=","1}/old/{p=""}{print $0p}' file`

Comment: Or `awk '{p=",0"}/aes/{p=",1"}/old/{p=""}{print $0p}'` :)

Comment: Or `sed '/aes/{s/.*/\0,1/;bn};/old/bn;s/.*/\0,0/;:n'` which is actually `1` char less. :D

Comment: Or `awk '{p=",0"}/aes/{p=",1"}/old/{p=""}{$0=$0p}7'` which is again `1` char less. :D :D .. However, I still think it is a typical `sed` task: Editing files.

Comment: @hek2mgl If you remove the redundant label, you can reduce your solution further more `sed '/aes/{s/.*/\0,1/;b};/old/b;s/.*/\0,0/' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk -F',' '{$4="0";} $1=="www" && $3=="aes"{$4="1";} $1=="old"{NF=NF-1}1' OFS=, yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '\#^www,/something else/,ese$# {s//&,1/;b;}
     \#^old,/something else/,ese$# b
     s/$/,0/' YourFile
```

the something else could be replaced by any pattern like `.*` but `#` (or use another delimiter)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following `sed` script:

`example.sed:`

```
# Append the 1 to www ... aes and got to next line in input
/www,\/something else\/,aes/ {s/.*/\0,1/;b next}

# Do nothing here and go to next line in input
/old,\/something else\/,ese/b next

# Append the 0 for all other lines
s/.*/\0,0/

# Label for above jump statements (b next)
:next
```

Execute it like this:

```
sed -f example.sed input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/$/,0/;s/^(www,/something else/,aes)..$/\1,1/;s/^(old,/something else/,ese)..$/\1/' file
```

Exactly as you described.